# Will having a credit freeze still allow a hard inquiry on my credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

If I have my credit files frozen with the 3 major bureaus, and I apply for a credit card or attempt to take out a loan, my understanding is that I should be immediately denied - as expected.

But will there still be a hard inquiry that shows up on my credit report?

Comment: I hope the answer is "No."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's the whole point of the freeze. Your credit is locked and will not be pulled.

They may not deny you, it's up to them. But they will not be able to see your credit report.